# ffmpeg enable between not working

Tags: ffmpeg

I cannot get the `enable='between(t,12,60)'` functionality of ffmpeg working. I've provided a sample command below. Removing the `between` statement works fine and the text shows up. Leaving the `between` statement shows no text.

```
ffmpeg -y -i %04d.png -filter_complex \
"drawtext=fontfile=/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf:text='Test Text':fontsize=100:enable='between(t,12,60)'" \
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -s hd1080 -framerate 25 -crf 23 -t 6 -threads 0 output.mp4
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `-t 6` in your command, so the output duration is 6 seconds, but your *between* is set for 12-60 seconds. Remove `-t 6`.